# PHP: How to use Regex to obtain text within link tags

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I would like to obtain the text within these link tags:

```
<a target="_blank" class="timestamp" href="http://www.link.com/1">10:55 am</a>
<a target="_blank" class="timestamp" href="http://www.link.com/2">3:30 pm</a>
```

So far, I have:

```
preg_match_all('/<a (.*?)<\/a>/s', $html, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Unfortunately, it returns everything between the two a's. Is there a way to just get the text between the a-tags, **meaning 10:55 am and 3:30 pm**, and nothing else?

Comment: A really rough regex: `<a[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>`

Comment: Doesn't work really isn't a description of why it isn't working. Well here's a [*proof*](http://regex101.com/r/xT2tC8/1) that it *does* work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. However, you might consider using something like [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) instead.

```
preg_match_all('/<a[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/s', $html, $matches);
```